# Open DICOMweb data

Tags: medical

I'm developing a university course that has the goal of students building their own DICOMweb viewer in Python using GTK and https://dicomweb-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Unfortunately the data stored in https://dicomcloud.azurewebsites.net is broken. All images referenced through the UID-links in studies and series are missing.

There is also

https://www.dicomlibrary.com/

but they don't provide a standardized DICOMweb-interface but only individual downloads.

Note that the server

https://dicomcloud.azurewebsites.net

used in

https://dicomweb-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#examples

is buggy as discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/clindatsci/dicomweb-client/issues/3#issuecomment-419660085).